# Const structure in doubly linked list is being modified in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, constants

I'm dealing with doubly linked lists and came an issue I'm not working around. To illustrate it better, here's is the code before I say what the issue is.

**Dblist.h**

```
# Ifndef CGI_DBLIST_H
# Define CGI_DBLIST_H
# Include "malloc.h"
/ * Structure represantative an element of the list. * /

typedef struct elem
{
     int value;
     struct elem * prev;
     struct elem * next;
} Elem;

/ * Structure access to the list. * /

typedef struct
{
     elem * first;
     elem * last;
} dblist;

# ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
# Endif
    void Init (dblist * l);                    /* Initialize the list  */
    void pushback (dblist * s, int val);       /* Add a value at end   */
    void PushFront (dblist * l, int val);      /* Add a value at start */
    int PopBack (dblist * l);                  /* Remove value at end  */
    int PopFront (dblist * l);                 /* Remove value at start */
    void View (dblist l);                      /* Display whole list   */
    void ViewReverse (dblist l);               /* Display all reversed */
    void Clear (dblist * l);                   /* discard list         */
    dblist getInterval (dblist const * s);

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif

  #endif /* CGI_DBLIST_H */
```

**Dblist.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dblist.h"
#include "malloc.h"

void Init (dblist * l)
{
   l-> first = NULL;
   l-> last = NULL;
}

void pushback (dblist * s, int val)
{
   elem * n = malloc (sizeof (elem));
   if (! n) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   n-> value = val;
   n-> prev = l-> last;
   n-> next = NULL;
   if (s-> last) s-> last-> next = n;
   else s-> first = n;
   l-> last = n;
}

void PushFront(dblist *l, int val)
{
   elem *n = malloc(sizeof(elem));
   if(!n) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   n->value = val;
   n->next = l->first;
   n->prev = NULL;
   if(l->first) l->first->prev = n;
   else l->last = n;
   l->first = n;
}

int PopBack(dblist *l)
{
   int val;
   elem *tmp = l->last;
   if(!tmp) return -1;
   val = tmp->value;
   l->last = tmp->prev;
   if(l->last) l->last->next = NULL;
   else l->first = NULL;
   free(tmp);
   return val;
}

int popFront(dblist*  l)
{
   int val;
   elem *tmp = l->first;
   if(!tmp) return -1;
   val = tmp->value;
   l->first = tmp->next;
   //if(l->first)l->first->prev = NULL;
   //else l->last = NULL;
   //free(tmp);
   return val;
}

dblist getInterval (dblist const * s) 
{
   dblist* intervals = NULL;
   memmove(&intervals, &l, sizeof(l));
   if(intervals->first)intervals->first->prev = NULL;
   else intervals->last = NULL;

   return *intervals;
}

void View (dblist l)
{
    elem *pelem = l.first;
    while (Pelem)
    {
       printf ("% d \ n", pelem-> value);
       pelem = pelem-> next;
     }
}

void ViewReverse (dblist l)
{
    elem* test = l.last;

    while (test)
    {
       printf("% d \ n", test-> value);
       test = test-> prev;
    }
}

void Clear (dblist * l)
{
   elem *tmp;
   elem *pelem = l->first;
   while(pelem)
   {
      tmp = pelem;
      pelem = pelem->next;
      free(tmp);
   }
   l->first = NULL;
   l->last = NULL;
}
```

**main.c**

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #include "dblist.h"

 int main ()
 {
    dblist pdbListe * = malloc (sizeof (dblist));
    dblist interval;

    Init (pdbListe);
    printf ("Pushin In The gains list\n");
    PushFront (pdbListe, 10);
    Pushback (pdbListe, 20);
    Pushback (pdbListe, 40);
    PushFront (pdbListe, 23);
    PushFront (pdbListe, 70);
    PushFront (pdbListe, 54);

    printf ("Viewing the list:\n");
    View (pdbListe *);
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("poping front capital gains from The Stack:\n");
    printf ("% d\n", PopFront (pdbListe));
    printf ("% d\n", PopFront (pdbListe));
    / / Printf ("% d\n", PopBack (pdbListe));
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("Viewing the list after pop front:\n");
    View (pdbListe *);
    puts ("--------------");
    printf ("this is pdbListe:% p\n", pdbListe);
    printf ("this is interval:% p\n", & interval);

    interval = getInterval (pdbListe);
    printf ("Viewing the interval\n");
    ViewReverse (interval);
    printf ("first element is:% d\n", interval.first-> value);
    printf ("last element is:% d\n", interval.last-> value);
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("Reverse Viewing the list after pop front:\n");
    ViewReverse (pdbListe *); // ISSUE HERE: it should print 6 elements not 4
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("this is pdbListe:% p\n", pdbListe);
    printf ("this is interval:% p\n", & interval);
    printf ("sizeof pdbListe% d\n", sizeof (pdbListe));
    printf ("sizeof interval% d\n", sizeof (interval));

    printf ("Pushing back a value in The List:\n");
    Pushback (pdbListe, 30);

    printf ("Viewing the list after push back:\n");
    View (pdbListe *);
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("In The Front popping list:\n");
    printf ("% d\n", PopFront (pdbListe));
    printf ("% d\n", PopFront (pdbListe));
    puts ("--------------");

    printf ("Viewing the list after pop front:\n");
    View (pdbListe *);
    puts ("--------------");
    printf ("Clearing the list\n");
    Clear (pdbListe);

    printf ("Freeing the list\n");
    free (pdbListe);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Don't care about the malloc.h, it is small utility I'm using to ensure correct memory usgae**

So the problem is the interval variable comes from `getInterval(const dblist *)`, I want it to hold only a part of the initial list when either `popBack` or `popFront` has been applied.

The problem is that if I make modifications to `getInterval`, it is influencing the values of `pdbListe`. For example try to modify `getInterval` like this (try to comment those lines as illustrated below):

```
dblist getInterval(const dblist* l) {
   dblist* intervals = NULL;
   memmove(&intervals, &l, sizeof(l));
   //if(intervals->first)intervals->first->prev = NULL;
   //else intervals->last = NULL;

   return *intervals;
}
```

From there one can see that not only the result returned by `getInterval` (in this case the interval variable in main.c) but also the `pdbListe` variable which by essence should never be modified!

What can I do to work around this? I want `pdbListe` to remain as such and never be affected by what `getInterval` is doing.

Comment: Sorry, the correct sentence is: "From there one can see that not only the result returned by getRange ( in this case the range variable in main.c ) but also the pdbListe variable is being modified which by essence should never be modified!!

Comment: Two things: Your code doesn't even compile, because some functions take an argument whose name is "s" but then attempt to use an undeclared variable named "l" (when they mean "s"), or vice versa.  Second, why on earth are you using memmove to copy a single pointer?  Did you mean to copy the thing that "l" *points to*?

Comment: Probably the code doesn't compile and I apologise for that. In fact it tooks a lot of editing to make the code readable so mistakes may be present but I'm sure I didn't alter the logic.That memcopy was for fun! You can just use the assigment operator (=) and it will do great, after a slight code modification! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want getRange to return a sublist, while the original list remains unmodified, then you need to modify how you terminate (put endpoints on) your list.  You will need to stop using NULL as an end marker and use comparison to the first/last element pointers instead.  For example:

```
void printList(dblist *list) {
  for (elem *e = list->first; e != list->last; e = e->next) {
    printf("%d ", e->value);
  }
}
```

Note the `e != list->last`, not `e != NULL`.

That way, you can make a sublist by constructing a dblist with new start/end points.  It no longer requires any modification to the underlying links (next and prev).

Comment: Randal, thanks for pointing that out. In fact as I wrote, there was change in behavior when I dropped using NULL as list endpoint's value. That's exactly what I mention when I proposed to comment some portion of getRange() [now getInterval()]. What I noticed was that when I run the ViewReverse() function on the range[interval] list, it prints out exactly the original list. In case I don't understand your suggestion well, please enlighten me BY GIVINF THE NEW CONSTRUCT OF THE getRange()[getInterval()] FUNCTION. Thanks

Comment: @Randall: I modified the getRange()[getInterval()] function like bellow, by taking into consideration your suggestion,and I got some interesting results: the original list isn't being modified but the new list still includes some elements(the one front popped) when I apply the ViewReverse() [not yet with the printList() construct you showed because I want to be quite surethe new list is within boundaries] function on the range. Here it goes:                       if(ranges->first)ranges->first->prev = l->first->prev;
else ranges->last = l->last;

Comment: @Randall: in fact, your answer has solved my problem! But if you can take into consideration my last issue and look into it, it will be of a greater help. Best Regards

Comment: In ViewReverse, you need to change "while (test)" to "while (test != l.first)", as "while (test)" is shorthand for a null check.

Comment: Ok. I understand that and I did the modification (it worked fine as a matter of fact). The question is why is the new sublist including the popped elements while I'm not longer including NULL as a end marker? it shouldn't! Try to run the ViewReverse with while(test), it shows that those elements still there. It should never! Do you have an idea of how to strip them away?

Comment: "while(test)" in ViewReverse is wrong.  It will print elements that are no longer part of the list.

Comment: Exactly and if those elements are no longer part of the list, the should never printed out even if while(test) is used! Is there anyway to get those elements out and to free the memory they are occupying? I mean some kind of free(test->first->prev). Thanks

Comment: Because when we return the new list, It is far better that it doesn't include elements from the old list if popFront was applied. But the fact is, those elements are still there because popFront here is only modifying the pointer to the first element. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem.  Either popFront modifies the underlying list structure or it doesn't.  If it does, then you don't have extra items before the start of the list, but then popFront isn't like getInterval where the original list remains valid.  If it doesn't, then those extra items before the start of the list still hang around.  No free lunch here, you need to pick which to do and deal with the consequences.

Comment: Your observation about memory management is a good one, deciding when it is OK to free an element is much harder when you don't NULL terminate everything.